# Elasticsearch with Python Requests: msearch request must be terminated by a newline

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using msearch with Python requests and get the following error:

*The msearch request must be terminated by a newline [\n]*

I have looked at many other related questions/answers, but they are either using cURL, a text file with the query, or the Python es API. I need to use requests and my query is generated as list/dictionaries.

```
url  = <host>+"/" +  'books/_msearch' # books is the index
region = <region>
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

payload = [{}, 
           {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"user_id": [504401]}}]}}, "size": 0},
          {}, 
          {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"user_id": [504401]}}]}}, "size": 0}
]
                   
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload)

query_results = json.loads(r.text)
```

I also tried:

```
payload = json.dumps(payload) + "\n"
```

Same error.

I also tried:

```
    r = ""
    for d in payload:
        r += json.dumps(d) + "\n"

    r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=r)
```

Same error.

Comment: Can you try the data arg instead of json?

Comment: That gives me another error: Content-Type header is missing

Comment: Set argument `headers` to `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}`. Also, can you change your POST body to be just a single dict instead of a list?

Comment: That did it! I needed to add a header, change json to data, and also include the "for d in search_arr:" bit to add \n

Comment: Nice! Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @wholevinski for the answer (in the question comments). I needed to change json to data and add headers. Also, I needed to do the \n loop.

```
payload = [{}, 
           {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"user_id": [504401]}}]}}, "size": 0},
          {}, 
          {"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"user_id": [504401]}}]}}, "size": 0}
] # same as in question

data_as_str = ""
for d in payload:
    data_as_str += json.dumps(d) + "\n"                 
    
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
# "Accept: text/plain" may not be necessary

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, auth=awsauth, data=data_as_str)

query_results = json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's coming across this 2+ years later, the change that fixed this for me was in the content-type:

```
{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
```

=>

```
{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson' } }
```

ndjson = "Newline delimited JSON"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
r = requests.post(url,
                  data="\n".join(
                      [json.dumps(elem) for elem in payload]
                  )+"\n",
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson'})
```

`Accept: text/plain` is an [unnecessary workaround](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-desc).

Comment: Thanks. This should also work I wrote out the answer as provided by @wholevinski  since that's what I went with.

Comment: Cool. Just because it works does not mean it’s correct 